# Regular Expression for negative accounting money values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am having a hard time finding a solution for negative accounting/money values that look like:

```
(1.00)

(100)

(100.00)
```

I've tried this, but for some reason, it's allowing values such as 'abcd'.

```
^0\.00||(\(\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\))?$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not match abcd, but if you test if the string has a match, then it will be true as there are positions that match.

As all the digits are optional at the end of the string, there is a position that can match.

Also the `||` matches a position after 0.00, before and after the digits part and on every position in abcd or an empty string.

---

You can change the `||` to `|`, match at least a single digit and use the alternation for both alternatives:

```
^(?:0\.00|\(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\))$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `0\.00` Match `0.00`
  - `|` Or
  - `\(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\)` Match `(` 1+ digits, optionally `.` and 1-2 digits and `)`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4nQcXQ/1)